# Spring Security refuse all request from client side

Tags: java, spring, reactjs, spring-security, spring-rest

I'm using ReactJS with Spring REST and Spring Security and when I do something like:

```
var myInit = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders,
  mode: 'cors',
  cache: 'default'
};

fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/employees", myInit)
  .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response.json());
    }
  )
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error.message);
  });
```

Browser respone this: `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` at `<!DOCTYPE..`.
I'm sure that this problem is the result of my WebSecurityConfig:

```
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/login", "/css/**", "/built/**").permitAll()
      .anyRequest().authenticated()
      .and()
      .formLogin()
      .loginPage("/login")
      .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
      .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
      .and()
      .httpBasic()
      .and()
      .logout()
      .logoutUrl("/logout")
      .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
      .and()
      .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
      .and()
      .csrf();
  }
```

Cause when I remove `anyRequest.authenticated`. It works again but I don't know how to fix.

Comment: How do you want to do the authentication? Your config wants authentication but nothing in your code provides security credentials or similar.

Comment: I don't clearly understand you. But I just focus on what make my request from js file is prevent by Spring security. JS file is compile to `/built` folder

Comment: The `fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/employees")` request needs to contain something that authenticates the request, like a session cookie, an api key, jwt or basic-auth username&password as http header. It may work if you go to `/login` manually before going to your react site since that should create a session with spring security's default config (and browsers should send the session cookie automatically along with fetch requests). You'll also want to change the error handling for rest-api requests to return 401 responses instead of a redirect to a `accessDeniedPage`.

Comment: I've login normally before fetching the url but it still not worked.

Comment: Do you want me to update some class/file?

Comment: I tried to use [https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1) and it works. But not local url

Comment: Check the request & response in your browsers dev console: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/resource-loading#view_details_for_a_single_resource - does it contain session cookie, and what does the error page in response contain?

Comment: yes, they did. the line chrome specified in the error page is `localhost/:1` which I mentioned above. the first character of `<!DOCTYPE`. It return HTML instead of JSON

Comment: It worked fine after I add `credentials: 'same-origin'` to fetch header. Thanks! @zapl